# Express Node.js framework: How to re-write a URL by replacing one of the named param segments?

Tags: redirect, node.js, express, parameters, routes

In my Express app, I'd like to perform some redirects when certain params from the route match certain criteria, using a route param pre-condition. As an example, let's say I want the param `word` to be converted to all upper-case, if it isn't already.

The param `word` might be present in several different routes, e.g. `/:word`, `/foo/:word`, `/foo/:word/bar`, etc. Fortunately, with route param pre-conditions, these are all handled by the same code, e.g. (code in CoffeeScript):

```
app.param 'word', (req, res, next, word) ->
  if word isnt word.toUpperCase()
    new_URL = // current URL, but replace word with word.toUpperCase() //
    res.redirect new_URL, 301
```

My question regards how to construct `new_URL`, replacing `:word` with its upper-case equivalent. I want to be able to use the same function to construct `new_URL`, regardless of which route is currently being used.

I see that there is `req.route`, but it is undefined. I guess I can access the currently matched route via `req.app.routes.routes.get[req._route_index]`, and then split the `path`, and re-construct it, but that seems overly complicated. Is there a way to simply iterate the `path` segments for the current route? Thanks!

Comment: You'll do better to put an actual answer to this question (so it is marked as answered) and then ask a new question about the location of your helper.

Comment: Thanks Jason King, that makes sense. I change my "update" to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a little function to replace a named route parameter with a new value. I'm not sure this is an optimal solution, and it is not a complete solution (it definitely won't work with nob-segment named params like `/:from-:to`).

```
replaceRouteParam = (req, param, replacement) ->
  segments = req.app.routes.routes.get[req._route_index].path.split('/')
  new_segments = []
  for segment in segments
    if segment is param
      new_segments.push replacement
    else if segment[0] is ':'
      new_segments.push req.params[segment[1..]]
    else
      new_segments.push segment

  new_segments.join '/'
```

The advice I got about using this function in multiple locations (my errors, routes, etc, which are in different files) was to put them in a separate file and require it in whichever files need it.